# where does Etherpad Lite store documents/pads?

Tags: node.js, etherpad

I am running Etherpad Lite on windows, and apparently it is persisting pads across shutdowns. But where? Does it run sqlite inside the node.exe process? What files does it use to store whichever database it might be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use dirtyDB as its datastore if you dont specify a **postgres**, **sqlite** or **mysql** configuration in `$APPDIR$/settings.json`

The dirtyDB file path is also set in the `settings.json` file. -- They recommend using dirtyDB only for testing.